# Use apply() with Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3), columns=list('bde'),index=['Utah','Ohio','Texas','Oregon'])

frame

b   d   e
Utah    0.479210    0.161892    -1.315375
Ohio    -0.572543   0.080203    -0.446178
Texas   0.052954    0.043417    0.365056
Oregon  1.462631    0.244453    2.207720

f = lambda x: x.max()-x.min() 
frame.apply(f)
```

This results to:

```
b    2.035174
d    0.201035
e    3.523095
dtype: float64
```

Im trying to learn how to apply the lambda to the specific column only so I  wanted to apply the lambda to the 'd' column only. So this is what I did

```
frame['d'].apply(f)
```

It results to an error though:
    AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'max'

```
type(frame['d'])
pandas.core.series.Series

frame['d'].dtype
dtype('float64')
```

I try to debug it. It seems that frame['d'] which is of type Series and each of the values in this series is a float and a float doesn't have a min/max attribute.

I thought I'm just missing something simple here, but my limited knowledge of Python and Pandas is giving me a hard time.  How do I get to apply the lambda to column 'd' only?

Comment: In this case, you can run `f` directly on the Series via `f(frame['d'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `.apply` on a Series works *elementwise*, in a `DataFrame` it works *by series* or *by row*. If you really want to use `.apply` this way, you can subset like this:

```
In [9]: frame.loc[:,['d']]
Out[9]: 
               d
Utah    2.259488
Ohio    0.458926
Texas  -0.072635
Oregon  0.470217

In [10]: type(frame.loc[:,['d']])
Out[10]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Which returns a `DataFrame`. So then you can simply do:

```
In [11]: frame.loc[:,['d']].apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
Out[11]: 
d    2.332124
dtype: float64
```

Note, for brevity you can simply use `frame[['d']]`, however, this makes more sense:

```
In [12]: frame.d.max() - frame.d.min()
Out[12]: 2.3321235565383334
```

**ETA:** In fact, even for the whole `DataFrame` you really don't need apply in this case, and it will certainly be slower than the following:

```
In [19]: frame.max() - frame.min()
Out[19]: 
b    3.337040
d    2.332124
e    2.224037
dtype: float64
```